# How to read "numeric form string data" without changing into integer data type？

Tags: r, types, read-data

I want to read data and specify the data type at the beginning.

I have csv data look like this, it's data type is "character"：

- Id
- "76561198042769362   "
- "76561198049454009   "
- "76561198066403163   "
- "76561198079071374   "

And when I read data, it gives me this：

> ```
> f<-read.csv('community_friendship.csv')
> ```

- ID
- 1 7.65612e+16
- 2 7.65612e+16
- 3 7.65612e+16
- 4 7.65612e+16
- 5 7.65612e+16

I try to transform it back to character, however, it round the origin data
so I can not have people's real ID

> ```
> as.character(f)
> ```

- ID
- "76561198042769360"
- "76561198049454016"
- "76561198066403168"
- "76561198079071376"
- "76561198083602880"

Do anyone know how to read origin data without transform data type？

Comment: Can you just use colClasses to declare ID as character? f <- read.csv('community_friendship.csv', colClasses=c(ID="character"))

Comment: @Ben oh~ It did work！ thanks a lot！
I did see this on R document but do not really understand what it is saying.